# How do I fix these mesh deformations I get when exporting from Blender to 3DS Max?

Tags: export, knife-tool

I have to export from Blender to 3DS Max in .obj format. I cut faces with *Knife Tool* (<kbd>K</kbd>), but when I imported to 3DS Max, I was presented with this problem on the edges.

Is there a solution for this problem?

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify, or add more information? That looks like overlapping geometry It's hard to understand what you want,maybe add a blend file or some more screenshots of your topology.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because you haven't defined the deformation in the node editor. I have a problem also getting the deformations in logicTrees/node-editor, but I am quite sure this is it. hf

Answer (score 0):

[image]

My blend files looks like that. I use knife to cut the mash. I exoprt the model in obj file and importing in 3ds max. [image]
And I have this overlapping faces. 
If I erase a face you can see the face under.[image]

I open in 3ds max(same version) the same file on an ather computer and overlapping faces doesn't appeard anymore. In this case,
where could be the problem?

The solution that I found so far is to have a better construction, without single point on faces. [image]

If you have better ideas please share.

Comment: this should be added as extra info in your question instead of an answer